# RemoveByPattern method is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

I'am facing the following issue with `ServiceStack PooledRedisClientManager()` in my `C#.net` application. `RemoveByPattern()` method is not avaliable.

Before we are using the `RedisClient()` and we are able to get the method.

Could you please help out there is any alternate method is available in `PooledRedisClientManager` for `RemoveByPattern`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.cs

With your `PooledRedisClientManager` you can get the `RedisClient` with `GetClient()` then call RemoveByPattern from this object.

By the way, `RemoveByPattern` use `Keys` command that should NOT be used in production environments. A better way should be to use `ScanAllKeys(yourPattern)` then iterate on the result list to remove all keys.

Comment: should `only` be used in production` : -> should be: should `not` be used in production

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Used the ScanAllKeys() and able to remove the keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is patched in ServiceStack v 5.6.1